# 'cbegin' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I'm trying to learn c++, so I wrote a short program.this is my c++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string line;
regex email(R"(\w+@(\w+\.)+\w+)");
while (getline(cin, line)) {
    smatch matches;
    auto current = cbegin(line);
    auto last = cend(line);
    while (current != last)
    {
        if (regex_search(current, last, matches, email))
        {
            ssub_match match = matches[0];
            current = match.second;
            cout << match.str() << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

```
=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===

C:\Users\Public\Documents\CPP Scripts\usingStringType.cpp||In function 'int main()':
C:\Users\Public\Documents\CPP Scripts\usingStringType.cpp|13|error: 'cbegin' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\Public\Documents\CPP Scripts\usingStringType.cpp|14|error: 'cend' was not declared in this scope

=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===
```

Comment: What compiler? And how do you call the compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if they're in the version you're running, but if they are, then `cbegin/cend` should be in <iterator>. If they're not (I guess C++14 is when they were added), you'll just need to use `line.cbegin()` and `line.cend()`.